# (answerd) find command in Bash SH is not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have s script like below, which should use 'find' to copy all files end with extention (in the list I gave) to the destination directory. however, it's not working. I tried to change ' to '', ''', ","",""" in line start with 'find' but still no luck.
could you please help to take a look, see what went wrong for my coding,  thanks a lot.

```
#!/bin/bash

vDirIn=/IN/
vDirOut=/OUT/
vAction="Copy"

vExtn="avi,mkv,mp4"

vExtnArr=($(echo "$vExtn" | tr ',' '\n'))

for vExtnArr_i in "${!vExtnArr[@]}"
do
    echo "$vExtnArr_i: ${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]}"

    if [ "$vAction" == "Copy" ]
    then
       find "$vDirIn" -name '*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]' -exec cp -rf {} $vDirOut \;
    else
       find "$vDirIn" -name '*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]' -exec mv -f {} $vDirOut \;
    fi

done
```

here is the debug message, this is why I keep changing at the 'find' line. the output looks funny as I think

```
bash -x ./CopyMediaFiles.sh
+++ readlink -f ./CopyMediaFiles.sh
++ dirname '/CopyMediaFiles.sh'
+ vPGMDir='/'
+ date
+ vDirIn=/IN/
+ vDirOut=/OUT/
+ vAction=Copy
+ vExtn=avi,mkv,mp4
+ vExtnArr=($(echo "$vExtn" | tr ',' '\n'))
++ tr , '\n'
++ echo avi,mkv,mp4
+ for vExtnArr_i in '"${!vExtnArr[@]}"'
+ echo '0: avi'
0: avi
+ '[' Copy == Copy ']'
+ find /IN/ -name '*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]' -exec cp -rf '{}' /OUT/ ';'
+ for vExtnArr_i in '"${!vExtnArr[@]}"'
+ echo '1: mkv'
1: mkv
+ '[' Copy == Copy ']'
+ find /IN/ -name '*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]' -exec cp -rf '{}' /OUT/ ';'
+ for vExtnArr_i in '"${!vExtnArr[@]}"'
+ echo '2: mp4'
2: mp4
+ '[' Copy == Copy ']'
+ find /IN/ -name '*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]' -exec cp -rf '{}' /OUT/ ';'
+ for vExtnArr_i in '"${!vExtnArr[@]}"'
```

Comment: Single quotes around the array references won't work for the find commands - you need to use double quotes. i.e. `'*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]'` will just be that string, rather than the extension you're trying to find.

Comment: Why iterate over the *names* in `vExtnArr`, when you only need the *values*?  And you can avoid having to loop at all, with suitable expansions (e.g. `find \( -name \*.${vExtn//,/ -name \*.} \) -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t "$vDirOut"`).

Comment: Amazing... The Bash folks will crawl over top one another to be the first to answer an off-topic question on command usage. But when an actual scripting question arises - complete with a debug session - they don't answer it and downvote it...

Comment: @Petesh you are right, thank you, I also missing } from my command, these TWO caused issues, thanks a lot.

Comment: @TobySpeight, this is good, now I know script can write in this way thank you.

Comment: @jww :) still people help me a lot, It just my mistake, however without them, I might need more time to see what went wrong. And now I learned I have to be more careful about what I type and go back to the basic scripting knowledge

Comment: Don't put the "sloution" in the question - put it in an answer.

Comment: `IFS=, read -a vExtnArr <<< "$vExtn"` is a much safer way to create an array from a comma-delimited string.

Comment: @chepner yes thanks a lot  tested and it  works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing a `}` from your find command?

```
-name '*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]'
```

Should it be this?

```
-name "*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]}"
```

Comment: you are right, thank you so much ,  and also I changed ' to ", it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

vDirIn=/IN/
vDirOut=/OUT/
vAction="Copy"

vExtn="avi,mkv,mp4"

vExtnArr=($(echo "$vExtn" | tr ',' '\n'))

for vExtnArr_i in "${!vExtnArr[@]}"
do
echo "$vExtnArr_i: ${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]}"

if [ "$vAction" == "Copy" ]
then
   find "$vDirIn" -name "*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]}" -exec cp -rf {} $vDirOut \;
else
   find "$vDirIn" -name "*.${vExtnArr[vExtnArr_i]}" -exec mv -f {} $vDirOut \;
    fi

done
```